# Why Adaboost SAMME needs f to be estimable?

Tags: decision-trees, multiclass-classification, mathematics, adaboost

I am trying to understand the mathematics behind [SAMME AdaBoost](https://web.stanford.edu/%7Ehastie/Papers/samme.pdf):

At some stage, the paper adds a constraint for `f` to be estimable:

[image]

I do not understand why this is required. Can someone explain a bit better why this restriction is needed?

As well, would be possible to use a different constraint than the one added in the paper that would make f estimable?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Think for a while, if $f$ is not estimable, it can have any constant added to it with no difference on the result of the process.

This means that if no other constraints are imposed, **$f$ is not well/uniquely defined and in fact represents a whole class of functionals**. This obviously needs to be fixed and some *natural* constraint needs to be added (to uniquely fix $f$).

On the other hand, the additional constraint can also be seen as a *free parameter of the process* which nevertheless needs to be fixed somehow **in a concrete instance of the process** in order to take place.

In an analogy with physics, the algorithm is *"gauge-invariant"*, but for any concrete physical problem to be solved **some "gauge" needs to be chosen and fixed**.

They choose to impose the *symmetric constraint* which reduces to the usual `AdaBoost` in the 2-class case.

One can impose another constraint on $f$ (than the symmetric one), choosing to satisfy other criteria if so desirable (as long as it can uniquely fix $f$).

For example, the general *non-symmetric constraint* is also valid:
$$f_1 + \dots + f_K = c$$

for arbitrary constant $c$. This also fixes $f$ uniquely and it can introduce bias favoring certain classes over others (eg for an imbalanced problem). Additionaly, unless $c=0$, does not reduce to the (symmetric) AdaBoost in 2-classes case (which may or may not be desirable).

Comment: This was a very clear answer. Thank you so much. I am just wondering, if I understood well, the outputs for the multiclass case are recoded in such a way that f_k will be 1 if k=c and -1/(K-1) otherwise. Therefore, the sum of them should be always equal to zero. Should this recoding change in case that a non-symmetric constrain is use?

Comment: @Aggamarcel, in general yes this will change if another constraint is imposed